# How to clean part of layer with KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, erase

I'm working on drawing tool with kineticJS. There is a problem. I can't clean part of layer. Algorithm of drawing: draw some line, use rubber for cleaning and then continue drawing. And then all clean parts of layer disappearing. They full, like before using rubber.

[Demo](http://widget.reklatsmasters.com/drawpad.html)

[Code: erase](https://github.com/ReklatsMasters/drawpad/blob/865d7dbe379db5b231f37d8507988a7d6f06deac/drawpad.js#L363)

[Code: draw](https://github.com/ReklatsMasters/drawpad/blob/865d7dbe379db5b231f37d8507988a7d6f06deac/drawpad.js#L355)

Answer (score 0):

layer.clear(x,y,width,height) will clear your canvas using context.clearRect(x,y,width,height).

But remember that Kinetic objects are retained so any objects previously on that canvas will automatically be redrawn.

That's why your canvas fills up again even after layer.clear.

Comment: I understood it. What shall I do?

Comment: Well, without reviewing nearly 500 lines of code(!) you could .hide() the object that does your temporary rubber-banding when the rubber-binding is done. (I think I see that's a Kinetic.Line called ._node)

Comment: I can try to create object of Kinetic.Clear (Kinetic.Erase) which will contain cleared areas. I think that so even it will be better.

Comment: KineticJS is a retained system which is opposite of html canvas which is a non-retained system.  Trying to create "erase zones" runs contrary to the spirit of KineticJS.  So to back up...What temporary object do you use to draw your rubber-band?  When the rubber-banding is done can't you just do .hide() on that object.  If you do .hide() then that object will both be invisible and will not respond to events.

Comment: @markE Is this why I get bad performance with a LARGE layer that sets clearBeforeDraw:false, but updates the x/y position of a single SMALL element often? Is it "drawing" the entire canvas even though there are no other objects on that layer? Also, are there any docs besides the tutorials and generated API docs? The latter has a LOT of stuff like "width: this sets the width". No added explanation or context, questions raised with no answers. (Width is bad example). Also the top section on any class tends to be cloned from Node and you have to scroll down to see actual properties.

Comment: "Under-the-hood" each layer is a separate canvas so if you just have 1 object on a layer then that specific canvas will erase/redraw but any other layers will not be redrawn.  Even a very large sized canvas takes up almost no time to clear (The browser just zero-fills an array and the GPU blits that array)  About the docs--agreed, they aren't well laid out.  Have you tried the tutorial site: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/